# how to implement unique func on a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, unique

Excuse me does anyone here know how can we remove duplicates from a string using unique func or any other func?

for example if i want to turn `"fdfdfddf"` into `"df"`
I wrote the code below but it seems it doesn't work

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>t;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string dd;
    vector<string>s;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>dd;
        s.push_back(dd);
       sort(s[i].begin(),s[i].end());
     unique(s[i].begin(),s[i].end());
      cout<<s[i]<<"\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique - read the docs, study the examples. Also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Sneftel, what does removing duplicate strings from an array have to do with with removing duplicate substrings from a string? I've voted to reopen.

Comment: If duplicates of the strings `'f'` and `'d'` are removed from `'fdfdfddf'`, an empty string is returned. I assume from your example that duplicate strings must contain at least two characters. That needs to be clarified.

Comment: You have not told us precisely what you are trying to do. Suppose the string were `'fddfddf'`. The repeated substrings of length two or more are `'fd'`, `'df'`, `'dd'` and `'fdd'`. How are these substrings to be used to produce a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), `unique`:

> Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

If you want to get rid of the excessive elements, you have to do that explicitly, e.g., by calling `erase` (as in the example in the documentation):

```
auto last = std::unique(s[i].begin(), s[i].end());
s[i].erase(last, s[i].end());
```